# Forgetting double equal-sign in php if-statement

Tags: php, eclipse, if-statement, aptana

While coding, i sometimes make the error of writing a single = instead of == in an if-statement. So lets say i have this:

```
<?php
$name = 'piet';
if($name == 'jan'){
    print 'hello jan';
}

?>
```

And i make a mistake and write this instead:

```
<?php
$name = 'piet';
if($name = 'jan'){
    print 'hello jan';
}

?>
```

This won't throw an error of course, since it is valid php code. However, i never use this short-hand notation, so if i enter it by mistake it will break the logic of my code without telling me why. Is there a solution for this? I am using aptana which is an editor based on eclipse. Is there any way i can add my own custom errors to an editor (or php) based on for example regular expressions? Or are there any other approaches to alert me whenever i make this mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the order to this:

```
if('jan' == $name) {
```

This is known under [`Yoda conditions`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions):

[image]

So if you now make the mistake:

```
if('jan' = $name) {
```

This will give you an error!

Comment: Correct answer this is. I would recommend `if(0 === strcmp('jan', $name) {`.  As noted in [strcmp](http://php.net/strcmp) you can run into some interesting behavior when comparing strings to numbers or hex. Plus who doesn't love exacting code?