# difference between $a==5 and 5==$a in php

Tags: php

Today I have faced a question, I was unable to answer it, 
I have tried by making a php program but was unable to find out the exact reason for it 
if $a=5 then both($a==5 and 5==$a) are giving me output as boolean true and,
if $a != 5 then both ($a==5 and 5==$a ) are giving me output as boolean false
**Can anyone tell me what is the difference between $a==5 and 5==$a from any language point of view.**

```
**Program**
$a = 3;
var_dump( 5==$a );
var_dump( $a==5 );
$a = 5;
var_dump( 5==$a );
var_dump( $a==5 );


**Output**
boolean false

boolean false

boolean true

boolean true
```

Comment: There's no difference you're just switching their positions.

Comment: The one is just called: yoda condition: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28840422/3933332 otherwise no difference

Answer (score 7):

Comparisons like that are not affected by which value you write first. However, it is best practice to put the literal first, e.g. `5 == $x` because if you mess up and only enter one equals sign, you'll get an error instead of an accidental value assignment, which is far easier to debug.

Comment: Never thought of that... I have always done the other way around, as I was thought about 20 years ago. Dang I'm old....

Comment: you may point out taht this comparaison is called `yoda` comparaison

Answer (score 0):

No difference

but `5 == $a` prevents some error if you forgot one '='.

For example $a = 1

- if you write if ($a = 5) - $a value becomes 5
- if you write if (5 = $a) - you got error

Answer (score 0):

It's just a technique, that prevents you from accidentally using assignment instead of comparison. The if operator happily accepts `$a = 5`, while `5 = $a` throws an error, preventing you from creating a nasty bug.

Answer (score 0):

`5 == $a` is logically the same as `$a == 5`

This format, commonly referred to as **yoda conditions** and does not affect the logical comparison.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions

It is preferred, commonly in PHP, to prevent accidental assignment in conditions, which will always evaluate as either truthy or falsy, but will not actually perform the indented condition check:

```
if ($a = 5) {
  // always run... oops
} else {
  // never run
}
```

The [WordPress PHP Coding Standards](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/#yoda-conditions) have a good explanation of this as well